# Javascript array isnt updated outside of componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch some data from a database, and add it to an array, and I'm doing this inside of `componentDidMount` so that i can later use it to set the initial state of my component. However, while the array is updated inside the `promise`, it doesn't seem to be updated outside. Any ideas? Here is the code for reference. I can include more if necessary.

```
    class Equations extends React.Component {
        state = {
          equations: [] 
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let equations = []
        db.collection("equations").get().then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                equations = [...equations, doc.data()]
            });

        console.log(`inside: ${equations.length}`)
        });
    console.log(`outside: ${equations.length}`)
    }

  render() {
     return <div>stuff</div>
  }
```

My database currently has two entries in the databse collection, so of course I would expect both logs to return 2. But only the inside log returns 2; the outside log returns 0 for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because the outside `console.log` is called before the inside, since it's a promise and it's asynchronous.

If you add `async/await` you will see that the outside will be updated.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let equations = []
    await db.collection("equations").get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            equations = [...equations, doc.data()]
        });
        console.log(`inside: ${equations.length}`)
    });
    console.log(`outisde: ${equations.length}`)
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! This fixed it, and I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `inside` log is inside of a promise, which means it is asynchronous. Without diving into the code, the `then` is your giveaway that it's a promise. It 'waits' for your data API to finish before returning a response, and then it logs the equations.

The `outside` log is not inside a promise, which means it is synchronous. As soon as `componentDidMount` is called (immediately after the component is mounted) it logs the equations, which will be an empty list.

Any activities that depend on the response from the database should be inside your promise's response block.